# Why is the graph (Voltage vs Current) of an ohmic object not exactly linear?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors, approximations

What are the reasons for the graph Voltage vs Current of an Ohmic object being approximately and not exactly linear? In other words, we accept its lineality, but in reality, it is not exactly linear. Why is this?

Comment: Please give an example with reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are very few materials, which show real Ohmic behavior, most materials the resistance is dependant from temperature , so the resistance changes with the current heating the wire.

Comment: Resistance change due to hearing would be a measurement error.